# Routes from new blueprint not found and getting 404

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a new blueprint for my flask app and for a new blueprint. Its routes are getting 404 errors.

This is the new Blueprint (shopify) views.py file:

```
...
shopify = Blueprint('shopify', __name__,
                    template_folder='templates', url_prefix='/shopify')


# @admin.before_request
@login_required
@role_required('admin')
def before_request():
    """ Protect all of the admin endpoints. """
    pass


@shopify.route('/app_launched', methods=['GET'])
# @helpers.verify_web_call
def app_launched():
    print("-----------------INICIO----------------")
    shop = request.args.get('shop')
    global ACCESS_TOKEN, NONCE

    if ACCESS_TOKEN:
        return render_template('welcome.html', shop=shop)

    # The NONCE is a single-use random value we send to Shopify so we know the next call from Shopify is valid (see #app_installed)
    #   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce
    NONCE = uuid.uuid4().hex
    redirect_url = helpers.generate_install_redirect_url(
        shop=shop, scopes=SCOPES, nonce=NONCE, access_mode=ACCESS_MODE)
    return redirect(redirect_url, code=302)
...
```

This is my app.py:

```
...
def create_app(settings_override=None):
    """
    Create a Flask application using the app factory pattern.

    :param settings_override: Override settings
    :return: Flask app
    """
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    dev_env = os.getenv('DEV_ENV')
    print("DEV ENV------"+str(dev_env))

    if dev_env == 'DEV':
        app.config.from_object('config.settings')
        app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py', silent=True)
    elif dev_env == 'PROD':
        app.config.from_object('config.settings_prod')
        app.config.from_pyfile('settings_prod.py', silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_object('config.settings_prod')
        app.config.from_pyfile('settings_prod.py', silent=True)

    stripe.api_key = app.config.get('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
    stripe.api_version = app.config.get('STRIPE_API_VERSION')
    middleware(app)
    error_templates(app)
    exception_handler(app)
    app.register_blueprint(admin)
    app.register_blueprint(page)
    app.register_blueprint(contact)
    app.register_blueprint(user)
    app.register_blueprint(billing)
    app.register_blueprint(stripe_webhook)
    app.register_blueprint(shopify)
    # app.register_blueprint(copy_writer)
    # app.register_blueprint(bet)
    template_processors(app)
    extensions(app)
    authentication(app, User)

    return app
...
```

This is the app folder structure:

```
/app
  /blueprints
    /shopify
      /templates
        welcome.html
      __init__.py
      views.py
  app.py
```

Every time a route inside shopify blueprints is requested I get 404 error, while in other blueprints they are working well.

```
 [22/Apr/2023:21:45:43 +0000] "GET /app_launchedHTTP/1.1" 404 11057 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" in 264289µs
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you remember about prefix? `GET /shopify/app_launched`?

Answer (score 0):

URL must be `GET /shopify/app_launched`